# Realm Android - Multiple RealmModule for mutiple libraries

Tags: java, android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I'm composing different libraries in order to create a single application. Each library used uses its own Realm which, when tested individually on specific test applications, do not produce any error.

The project setup is the following

```
|- app
|- library\
|    |- LibraryOneRealmModule
|
|- library2
|    |- LibraryTwoRealmModule
|
```

where both `LibraryOneRealmModule` and `LibraryTwoRealmModule` are `RealmModule`s declared as follow:

```
@RealmModule(library = true, allClasses = true)
public class LibraryOneRealmModule{
}



@RealmModule(library = true, allClasses = true)
public class LibraryTwoRealmModule{
}
```

Now, when I try to put togheter two two module, the code that I'm using is the following:

```
Realm.init(this);

RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .modules(Realm.getDefaultModule(), new LibraryOneRealmModule(), new LibraryTwoRealmModule())
        .build();

Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
```

When I try to run the application I get an Exception telling me that a migration s needed because `LibOneRealmObject` has been added. Even if this is strange because the object is inside `library1`, I tried seting-up the migration object as follows:

```
class MyMigration implements RealmMigration {

    @Override public void migrate(@NonNull DynamicRealm realm, long oldVersion, long newVersion) {

        if (oldVersion == 0) {
            RealmSchema schema = realm.getSchema();
            RealmObjectSchema missingObject = schema.create("LibOneRealmObject");
            missingObject.addField("value", double.class);
            oldVersion++;
        }

    }

}
```

and then changing the `Realm` configuration as follows:

```
Realm.init(this);
RealmConfiguration realmConfig = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
        .migration(new SellMigration())
        .schemaVersion(1)
        .modules(Realm.getDefaultModule(), new OrdersRealmModule(), new CartRealmModule())
        .build();

try {
    Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(realmConfig);
    Realm.migrateRealm(realmConfig);
} catch (Exception e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
}
```

But when I try again to run the application and the code tries to access the `Realm` instance, the same error appears telling me:

```
io.realm.exceptions.RealmMigrationNeededException: Migration is required due to the following errors:

- Class 'LibOneRealmObject' has been added.
```

Please note that the code that throws the exception is inside `library1`, and is the following:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.where(MyObject.class).findAllSorted();
```

What should I do in order to solve this issue? 
Is it something related to the code inside `library1`? Or is it something inside the `app` module during the setup?

Comment: why do you use `allClasses` for both modules? They will both contain all model classes for `library` and `library2`. That may create pain and unnecessary migration dependencies for each lib.

Comment: @beeender Do you suggest listing all the classes iniside each library? I use this becasue the libraries are developed inside different Android Studio projects, then packed up and included as common dependencies

Comment: `.modules(Realm.getDefaultModule(), new LibraryOneRealmModule(), new LibraryTwoRealmModule())` this line will generate a schema which has all models in the libOne and libTwo. that's why you need to deal with the migration with libOne as well. If you don't need linking objects across libs, i think you should use separated configs for libOne, libTwo and you application.

Answer (score 2):

I've solve my issues as follow.

**1.** I've created a class in both `library1` and `library` with the following code:

```
public class Lib1Realm {

    private static final String REALM_NAME = "my.lib1.realm";
    private static RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration;

    private CartRealm(){}

    public static Realm getDefaultInstance() {
        if (realmConfiguration == null) {
            realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .name(REALM_NAME)
                    .modules(new LibraryOneRealmModule())
                    .build();
        }

        return Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
    }

}
```

And

```
public class Lib2Realm {

    private static final String REALM_NAME = "my.lib2.realm";
    private static RealmConfiguration realmConfiguration;

    private CartRealm(){}

    public static Realm getDefaultInstance() {
        if (realmConfiguration == null) {
            realmConfiguration = new RealmConfiguration.Builder()
                    .name(REALM_NAME)
                    .modules(new LibraryTwoRealmModule())
                    .build();
        }

        return Realm.getInstance(realmConfiguration);
    }

}
```

**2.** I've replaced all the `Realm.getDefaultInstance()` inside the `library1` and `library2` code with `Lib1Realm.getDefaultInstance()` and `Lib2.getDefaultInstance()` respectevly.

**3.** I let the `app` module which includes `library1` and `library2` as dependencies initialize the `Realm` instance by simply calling `Realm.init(this)` inside a class which extends `com.android.Application`.

This is what is working on for me. 
As it looks like, the problem was that the two modules were creating a single instance of the `Realm` object, which then lead to conflicts. 
Separating the libraries configuration adding some code was the best choice that could have been taken in order to make everything work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
RealmObjectSchema missingObject = schema.get("LibOneRealmObject");
if(missingObject == null) {
    missingObject = schema.create("LibOneRealmObject");    
    missingObject.addField("value", double.class);
}
oldVersion++;
```